# Java Gui Radiobutton to stop playing

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, jradiobutton

EDIT: I fixed my code and managed to get the song to work on the first radio button. But now If i unclick the button, the song will just start over instead of stopping. How do I make the song stop once the button has been clicked again, i tried a null but its not working.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class RadioControls extends JPanel
{
private JRadioButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;
private AudioClip[] music;
private AudioClip current;
private JSlider vSlider;
private JCheckBox airC;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Sets up the GUI
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public RadioControls()
{
URL url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6;
url1 = url2 = url3 = url4 = url5 = url6 = null;

// Obtain and store the audio clips to play
try
{
url1 = new URL ("file", "localhost", "westernBeat.wav");
url2 = new URL ("file", "localhost", "classical.wav");
url3 = new URL ("file", "localhost", "jeopardy.au");
url4 = new URL ("file", "localhost", "newAgeRythm.wav");
url5 = new URL ("file", "localhost", "eightiesJam.wav");
url6 = new URL ("file", "localhost", "hitchcock.wav");
}
catch (Exception exception) {}

music = new AudioClip[7];
music[0] = null;  // Corresponds to "Make a Selection..."
music[1] = JApplet.newAudioClip (url1);
music[2] = JApplet.newAudioClip (url2);
music[3] = JApplet.newAudioClip (url3);
music[4] = JApplet.newAudioClip (url4);
music[5] = JApplet.newAudioClip (url5);
music[6] = JApplet.newAudioClip (url6);

b1 = new JRadioButton("1");
    b1.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    b2 = new JRadioButton("2");
        b2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    b3 = new JRadioButton("3");
        b3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    b4 = new JRadioButton("4");
        b4.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    b5 = new JRadioButton("5");
        b5.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    b6 = new JRadioButton("6");
        b6.setBackground(Color.yellow);

//slider
vSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1, 5, 1);
vSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
vSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
vSlider.setPaintTicks(true);

//air
airC = new JCheckBox("On/Off");
airC.setBackground(Color.cyan);


//add buttons
add (b1);
add (b2);
add (b3);
add (b4);
add (b5);
add (b6);
add (vSlider);
add (airC);


b1.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

}

//*****************************************************************
//  Represents the action listener for both control buttons.
//*****************************************************************
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if(source==b1)
        music[1].play();

        //I think the problem is here****//
        if(source==null)
        music[0].play();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code runs everytime an event occurs on the button (regardless check or uncheck)

You need to check the button status like this:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if(source==b1){
             if(b1.isSelected()){
                 music[1].play();
             }
             else{
                 music[1].stop()
             }
        }

    }
```

You should also consider stopping the songs with .stop() rather then pointing the a null song.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an actionlistener to the button like this:

```
JRadioButton myRadioButton = new JRadioButton("");
myRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // Do something here...
    }
});
```

To do the same with a checkbox it's pretty much the same:

```
JCheckBox b = new JCheckBox("JCheckBox");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               //change Image here
            }
        });
```

To show an image, there are multiple things you could do. One would be:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL); 
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

You could hide the imageLabel onstart (I think 
    imageLabel.setVisible(false); 
would do that) and then put 
    imageLabel.setVisitble(true);
in your actionListener

Comment: I know how to set up the ActionListener i just dont understand how i get it to call the music file to play

Comment: I got the music to play, but now i cant get it to stop, I will update my code in a second.